# ImportError: No module named unstable

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, gui

I get the following error when I execute the `gui.py` script on my newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Please help as I have recently started using Ubuntu, I am not too good at debugging yet.

I get this error when I am trying to open the GUI of an open source software RevKit

```
sushanttrivedi@ubuntu:~/project/revkit-1.3$ ./tools/gui/gui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/gui/gui.py", line 143, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
  File "./tools/gui/gui.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.setupTools()
  File "./tools/gui/gui.py", line 102, in setupTools
    import items.unstable
ImportError: No module named unstable
```

What exactly is this error? is it because there is some background package missing?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What it is saying is that within "items" there is no module named "unstable".

Some things to try:

Open a terminal and run the python interpreter and `import items` and then try `help(items)`.

You might be able to try `sudo pip install items` or `sudo pip install revkit_python`

Although it seems like `items` is a specific module related to revkit.

Some files might need to be made try: `./configure; make && make install` within the revkit folder.